# Turing machine Representation for string of 3 letters

Tags: turing-machines

Can someone explain to me what this statement implies? I am assuming that it means that a string consisting of three characters repeated. What I don't understand is if the repeated string is all 0s or all 1s or both?

Give the state diagram of a machine (any Turing-Complete model) that decides the following languages over {0,1}:

{w : w = xxx, x ∈ Σ*}

Answer (score 1):

The language you are trying to decide here is `xxx`: that is, three copies of `x`. What is `x`? Well, it can be anything in $\Sigma *$: any string in your alphabet. (Usually this means "any binary string", but you can also use a different alphabet, the principle will be the same.)

So you're looking for any string which consists of something repeated three times. So strings in the language include `111`, and `000`, and `ε` (the empty string), and `100100100`, and `101011010110101`.

As for the machine that recognizes this, recognizing the language `xx` : $x \in \Sigma *$ is a classic demonstration of the power of Turing machines (since this language is neither regular nor context-free). Try starting from that machine and seeing what changes you'd need to make for `xxx`.